# How to access different session for admin and user on same browser with different window tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, angular8

I am working on a project. Where my requirement is that, if admin is logged in and he want to customise his frontend site, then he make changes accordingly and click on preview where he check his changes in new window tab using iframe. But my problem is that, because admin is logged in the same browser, so when he access his frontend site in new tab with iframe. then that site also shown the admin panel. Because admin is already logged in . I tried to open it in private window but unable to find any solution for that. Have any one know the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no clean way to do it on UI side only. Some time ago browsers allowed to open link in incognito mode, but it's not supported at the moment.
It makes sense to think about kind of 'sharing' functionality for the view you want to show. And identify user there by specific parameter/token in query string.

Comment: If you need to show your website in "public" mode, just add a parameter to the URL that you check for in the authentication flow and if present then exit it. Something like random-url.com/foo/bar **?noAuth=1**

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use sessionStorage to store your user sessions and manage authentication and authorization. Every time you open a new tab, it's treated as a new session and the login is not transferred.

SessionStorage is similar to LocalStorage but is bounded to a window and its lifecycle. You can find more details about it below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage